# Typescript breakpoints with VSCode

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, source-maps

I've this [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) scaffolded project from the [generator-express-no-stress-typescript](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress-typescript) template. I need to debug it, as in "step through the typescript code" with Visual Studio Code (and no, `console.log()` is not enough for me).

As per [the docs](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress-typescript#debug) I only need to issue

```
npm run dev:debug
```

and then attach VSCode. Here is the problem: if I do that, VSCode can't bind the breakpoints. If I make the debugger stop on the first execution line (`"stopOnEntry": true`), it stops in the generated JavaScript code instead of the source TypeScript code, and/but the filename in the tab title shows "index.ts" (not .js) in italics.

Here is the `dev:debug` script target in package.json:

```
"dev:debug": "nodemon --exec \"node -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk\" server/index.ts | pino-pretty",
```

and here is the "Attach" configuration in my `launch.json`:

```
    {
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "port": 9229,
        "request": "attach",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
        "type": "node",
        // "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
    },
```

Since this did not work, I tried a few other tutorials out there, and one (I can't remember which one) made me add the following configuration to my launch.json:

```
   {
       "name": "Run and debug",
       "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server/index.ts",
       "request": "launch",
       "skipFiles": [
           "<node_internals>/**"
       ],
       "type": "node",
       // "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"],
       "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "--preserve-symlinks"],
       "runtimeExecutable": "node",
       "args": ["--inspect", "${workspaceFolder}/server/index.ts"],
       "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",           
   }
```

This seemed promising at first, but then, when I tried it, it stepped through JS code instead of TS, just like the "Debug (Attach)" configuration above.

Here is the generated JS code that the debugger uses to trace execution. Please note that it contains the sourcemap in the commment at its end.

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
var _a, _b;
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("./common/env");
const server_1 = __importDefault(require("./common/server"));
const routes_1 = __importDefault(require("./routes"));
const models_1 = __importDefault(require("./api/models"));
const port = parseInt((_a = process.env.PORT) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : '3000');
const syncdb = ((_b = process.env.SYNC_DB_SCHEMA_ON_STARTUP) !== null && _b !== void 0 ? _b : 'false') === 'true';
if (syncdb) {
    models_1.default.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
        console.log("DB Aggiornato");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Errore", err);
    });
}
exports.default = new server_1.default().router(routes_1.default).listen(port);
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

I decoded the base64 sourcemap and it seems to contain the correct paths to my sources and even a copy of the source code:

```
{"version":3,"file":"/home/lucio/myapp/server/index.ts","sources":["/home/lucio/myapp/server/index.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;AAAA,wBAAsB;AACtB,6DAAqC;AACrC,sDAA8B;AAC9B,0DAA8B;AAC9B,MAAM,IAAI,GAAG,QAAQ,CAAC,MAAA,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,IAAI,mCAAI,MAAM,CAAC,CAAC;AAGlD,MAAM,MAAM,GAAG,CAAC,MAAA,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,yBAAyB,mCAAI,OAAO,CAAC,KAAK,MAAM,CAAC;AAE7E,IAAI,MAAM,EAAE;IACR,gBAAE,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,EAAE,KAAK,EAAE,IAAI,EAAE,CAAC,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,GAAG,EAAE;QACzC,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,eAAe,CAAC,CAAC;IACjC,CAAC,CAAC,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,CAAC,GAAQ,EAAE,EAAE;QAClB,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,QAAQ,EAAE,GAAG,CAAC,CAAA;IAC9B,CAAC,CAAC,CAAC;CACN;AAGD,kBAAe,IAAI,gBAAM,EAAE,CAAC,MAAM,CAAC,gBAAM,CAAC,CAAC,MAAM,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,CAAC","sourcesContent":["import './common/env';\nimport Server from './common/server';\nimport routes from './routes';\nimport db from './api/models';\nconst port = parseInt(process.env.PORT ?? '3000');\n\n\nconst syncdb = (process.env.SYNC_DB_SCHEMA_ON_STARTUP ?? 'false') === 'true';\n\nif (syncdb) {\n    db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {\n        console.log(\"DB Aggiornato\");\n    }).catch((err: any) => {\n        console.log(\"Errore\", err)\n
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`, just in case it matters:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "inlineSourceMap": true, // added after answer below, still doesn't work
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization":false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."

  },
  "include": ["server/**/*.ts", "server/api/models/index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./test/", "./dist"]
}
```

And here is the output of `npx ts-node --showConfig` (after
beautifulcoder's [comment to his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72403194/typescript-breakpoints-with-vscode#comment128076693_72494625))

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "cwd": "/home/lucio/myapp",
    "projectSearchDir": "/home/lucio/myapp",
    "project": "/home/lucio/myapp/tsconfig.json"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "outDir": "./.ts-node",
    "typeRoots": [
      "/home/lucio/myapp/node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "inlineSourceMap": false, // PLEASE NOTE: this is false even after I added `"inlineSourceMap": true` in tsconfig.json above
    "inlineSources": true,
    "noEmit": false
  }
}
```

I've scaffolded a new minimal example generator-express-no-stress-typescript project, following [the documented procedure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-no-stress) again. e.g.

```
$ npm install -g yo generator-express-no-stress
$ yo express-no-stress ts-debug-test
```

and choosing "OpenAPI 3" over "Swagger 2" when asked, which is what I did with the real project when I scaffolded it the first time. If you need a minimal example showing the problem you can do that too or you can find mine [at GitHub](https://github.com/lucrus73/ts-debug-test), if you prefer. I've only added my launch.json to it and you only need to set a breakpoint [at the first meaningful line of code](https://github.com/lucrus73/ts-debug-test/blob/9c09777118ba57ae1142e40dbe1eebd8b8da8969/server/index.ts#L5).

So now I don't know what to do next in order to debug my code... any clues?

Comment: Have you tried nuking `nodemon`?

Comment: Not yet, I did not know it could help. What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was being caused (the real bug was being triggered) by a symlink in the path where I store my project, e.g.

```
/home/lucio/myapp -> /home/lucio/workspace/vscode/myapp
```

The real bug is in VSCode, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34627).

The straghtforward workaround is to avoid symlinks in the project folder path.

Answer (score 4):

I think the `outFiles` property in your `Debug (Attach)` configuration is likely the problem. `ts-node` doesn't actually write its generated files and source maps to disk, so if VS Code is looking for them there then it won't find them. You should just be able to remove this property.

I have a number of codebases that use `ts-node` and `nodemon` in basically exactly the way you're using them here, and source mapping works fine. The only difference I can see is that my debug configurations don't have `outFiles` set.

---

**EDIT**: since the `outFiles` thing didn't work, the only other thing I can think of is that it's something in `tsconfig.json`. Here's one of mine that works. My guess is that it might be the `"inlineSourceMap": true`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "../interface/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to remove outFiles from launch.json, but nothing changed. At the very least, I've understood what `outFiles` is supposed to do.

Comment: Ok, I've added my `tsconfig.json` to the answer in case that helps.

Comment: Edited my question. Please note the comment in the `npx ts-node --showConfig` output. I don't know why it is still showing `false`.

Comment: I even tried your `tsconfig.json` but it  did not solve the problem in my case.

Comment: I hate wasting reputation points and they're about to expire, so I award them to you, without accepting your answer, because, despite your answer did not solve my problem, your suggestions helped me a lot in understanding how things work. The bounty aside, if you have any other suggestions they are very welcome, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.

Comment: Adding  `"inlineSourceMap": true` solved it for me. I was dealing with the same problem, trying to debug strapi 4.8.1 + typescript inside docker container

Answer (score 1):

My current theory is you have the debug script running behind `nodemon`. This is a node process monitor meant for production and not for debugging purposes on local.

Try:

```json
{"dev:debug": "node -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk server/index.ts"}
```

Comment: Just tried, thanks but no dice: it traces the generated JS code instead of the source TS, e.g. just the same problem as above.

Comment: I bet `ts-node` doesn't spit out source maps. There is probably a way to do this.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#configuration-1

Comment: I've edited my question adding the output of `npx ts-node --showConfig`. I don't know what I should look for in that output, except `"sourceMap": true` which is already there.

Comment: Yes, this is correct and it looks good. I'm stumped, can you post [minimal reproducible codes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on GitHub? I'm actually morbidly curious.

Comment: I've published a minimal example here: https://github.com/lucrus73/ts-debug-test and updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As I just figured out - this might be due to a VSCode console not utilizing proper node version.

In case you are using `nvm` (or something similar) - this can easily be the case.

Setup wasn't working anyhow, with any options enumerated here or in any other similar threads (meaning it did started, but breakpoints where not hit).

But as soon as I added proper version to my `launch.json` (in my case `"runtimeVersion": "12.22.12"`) - everything started to work with simplest defaults...

For the referrence:

My "default" `node` version was `8.x.x`.

`launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "runtimeVersion": "12.22.12",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "runtimeExecutable": "node",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node12/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, adding "runtimeVersion" in launch.json was the only thing that solved my problem. I'm using VSCode on a Mac, and i use nvm to manage multiple node versions and i just could not make the debugger to run and stop any breakpoint.